# Type mismatch Error when naming table headers

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to add ListColumns to a table I created in the code. I'm using an array to pull the range of cells from another sheet in a different file, to make a template of the table. When I look into the Locals window, the array is pulling the data correctly, just not renaming the headers. I'm getting an error at the commented line:

```
Dim i As Long
Dim hdrs, hdrs2

hdrs = Array(srcSheet.Range("A1:K1").Value2)
hdrs2 = Array(srcSheet2.Range("A1:I1").Value2)

xlSheet2.ListObjects.Add.Name = "tblData"
xlSheet3.ListObjects.Add.Name = "tblCodes"
Set tbl = xlSheet2.ListObjects("tblData")
Set tbl2 = xlSheet3.ListObjects("tblCodes")

With tbl
    For i = 0 To UBound(hdrs)
        .ListColumns.Add
        .ListColumns(.ListColumns.Count).Name = hdrs(i) '< Type Mismatch error
    Next i
End With
```

The srcSheet is the current(ThisWorkbook) sheets, and the xlSheets are the sheets in the other files. The first column is a Date field.
I only included the one array set, as I'm sure the other would have the same problem.
Thank you

Comment: Read http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx for how to work with arrays from a range. Hint: you don't use `Array`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would populate the array as this:

```
hdrs = Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(srcSheet.Range("A1:K1"))) 'Import range to array
```

---

Example code:

To create a 1D array:

```
Sub Alt1 ()
Dim hdrs, hdrs2
Dim sh As Worksheet

Set srcSheet = Sheet1

hdrs = Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(srcSheet.Range("A1:K1"))) 'Import range to array

For i = LBound(hdrs) To UBound(hdrs)
Debug.Print hdrs(i)
    Cells(i + 1, "A").Value = hdrs(i) '< Type Mismatch error
Next i

End Sub
```

To create more dimension (2D in this example) to the array:

```
Sub Alt2()

Dim hdrs, hdrs2
Dim sh As Worksheet

Set srcSheet = Sheet1

hdrs = srcSheet.Range("A1:K1").Value 'Import range to array

For i = LBound(hdrs, 2) To UBound(hdrs, 2) 'Notice that we need to change the upper bound definition
    Cells(i + 1, "A").Value = hdrs(1, i) '< Type Mismatch error
Next i

End Sub
```